# Oracle XML many nodes

Tags: oracle, xml-parsing

I have the following XML in table TEST_XML with one COLUMN "XMLTEXT" that is of type CLOB.

I want to receive the following table-like results at the end:

```
User_Identity                       Product_offer_ID   Keyword
testxmloralcemultynodes@gmail.com   11990              34861
testxmloralcemultynodes@gmail.com   11990              35357
testxmloralcemultynodes@gmail.com   11990              34841
```

XML Content:

```
  <MakeOfferEDRs>
    <EDRs>
     <MakeOffer status="6" bonusRuleID="119621" rewardActionID="191032" rewardTime="2023-09-   07T14:19:56" brandID="1" accountID="11712960353450032">
      <Parameter name="[LOOPBACK_RECOMMENDED_OFFER]">1</Parameter>
      <Products>
       <Product keyword="34861" id="22146"/>
       <Product keyword="35357" id="23146"/>
       <Product keyword="34841" id="22140"/>
       </Products>
      <RecommendationParameters>
       <ProductsNumber max="5"/>
       <Strategies>
        <Strategy name="5 RetSS 1 chain version_all MF Bands" id="16384"/>
       </Strategies>
      </RecommendationParameters>
      <ProductOfferingID>11990</ProductOfferingID>
      <UserIdentities>
       <UserIdentity triggered="1" type="EMAIL">testxmloralcemultynodes@gmail.com</UserIdentity>
      </UserIdentities>
      <UseCaseRunId>20662</UseCaseRunId>
      <UseCaseTypeId>5</UseCaseTypeId>
      <ScheduledCampaignID>62179</ScheduledCampaignID>
    </MakeOffer>
   </EDRs>
```

I tried a couple of queries, based on this one, where you'll see that I can either get the    original values in one row (column "Keyword" result `<Product id="22146" keyword="34861"/><Product    id="23146" keyword="35357"/><Product id="22140" keyword="34841"/>`) or merged all three result in   one value (column "Keyword2" result "348613535734841"):

```
select x.* from VGRAMATOV.TEST_XML t, xmltable (
'MakeOfferEDRs/EDRs'
passing xmltype(t.xmltext) 
  columns   
     User_Identity                 XMLTYPE    path './MakeOffer/UserIdentities/UserIdentity',
     Product_Offering_ID           XMLTYPE    path './MakeOffer/ProductOfferingID',
     Keyword                       XMLTYPE    path './MakeOffer/Products/Product',
     Keyword2                      XMLTYPE    path './MakeOffer/Products/Product/@keyword'
        ) as x
```

Answer (score 0):

Descend into `Products/Product` to get each keyword and then go back up the hierarchy to get th other values:

```sql
SELECT x.*
FROM   TEST_XML t
       CROSS APPLY XMLTABLE(
         '/MakeOfferEDRs/EDRs/MakeOffer/Products/Product'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(t.xmltext)
         COLUMNS
           User_Identity       VARCHAR2(200) path './../../UserIdentities/UserIdentity',
           Product_Offering_ID NUMBER path './../../ProductOfferingID',
           Keyword             NUMBER path '@keyword'
       ) x
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_xml (xmltext) AS
SELECT '<MakeOfferEDRs>
    <EDRs>
     <MakeOffer status="6" bonusRuleID="119621" rewardActionID="191032" rewardTime="2023-09-   07T14:19:56" brandID="1" accountID="11712960353450032">
      <Parameter name="[LOOPBACK_RECOMMENDED_OFFER]">1</Parameter>
      <Products>
       <Product keyword="34861" id="22146"/>
       <Product keyword="35357" id="23146"/>
       <Product keyword="34841" id="22140"/>
       </Products>
      <RecommendationParameters>
       <ProductsNumber max="5"/>
       <Strategies>
        <Strategy name="5 RetSS 1 chain version_all MF Bands" id="16384"/>
       </Strategies>
      </RecommendationParameters>
      <ProductOfferingID>11990</ProductOfferingID>
      <UserIdentities>
       <UserIdentity triggered="1" type="EMAIL">testxmloralcemultynodes@gmail.com</UserIdentity>
      </UserIdentities>
      <UseCaseRunId>20662</UseCaseRunId>
      <UseCaseTypeId>5</UseCaseTypeId>
      <ScheduledCampaignID>62179</ScheduledCampaignID>
    </MakeOffer>
   </EDRs>
</MakeOfferEDRs>' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| USER_IDENTITY | PRODUCT_OFFERING_ID | KEYWORD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| testxmloralcemultynodes@gmail.com | 11990 | 34861 |
| testxmloralcemultynodes@gmail.com | 11990 | 35357 |
| testxmloralcemultynodes@gmail.com | 11990 | 34841 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-l-lORhq)

Comment: Thank you! Appreciated!